# symfony doesn't like PostgreSQL with doctrine:build-schema

Tags: postgresql, symfony1, doctrine

I'm having a weird thing happen when I run `doctrine:build-schema` with my PostgreSQL database. It should just work, of course, but instead I'm getting this:

```
jason@ve:~/salon$ ./symfony doctrine:build-schema
>> doctrine  generating yaml schema from database


  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"                                               
  LINE 6: ...                                                  t.typtype ...                                                        
                                                               ^. Failing Query: "
SELECT                                            
ordinal_position as attnum,                                                  
column_name as field,                                                        
udt_name as type,                                                            
data_type as complete_type,                                                  
t.typtype AS typtype,                                                        
is_nullable as isnotnull,                                                    
column_default as default,                                                   
(                                                                            
  SELECT 't'                                                                 
  FROM pg_index, pg_attribute a, pg_class c, pg_type t                     
  WHERE c.relname = table_name AND a.attname = column_name                 
  AND a.attnum > 0 AND a.attrelid = c.oid AND a.atttypid = t.oid           
  AND c.oid = pg_index.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY (pg_index.indkey)       
  AND pg_index.indisprimary = 't'                                          
  AND format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) NOT LIKE 'information_schema%'  
) as pri,                                                                    
character_maximum_length as length                                           
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS                                                
WHERE table_name = 'salon'                                                     
ORDER BY ordinal_position"
```

Any idea why this is happening?

The crappy part is that even if I can fix the SQL query, the real problem is that symfony/Doctrine is not working as expected. Doctrine claims to support PostgreSQL it appears that other people are using PostgreSQL with `build-schema` without problems, so this is weird.

I'm on symfony 1.4.8 and Doctrine 1.2.

Comment: This looks like a bug, so why not report it?
Also, I guess you are building from a schema.yml file. Try deleting the half of it, then rebuild, and if you still get the error, try deleting half of the remaining class definitions, and so on until you know what particular definition causes the error. Also, have you tried switching to another DBMS to see it this occurs only with PostgreSQL?

Comment: That would normally be a good suggestion, but I'm not building from the schema.yml file. I'm building the schema.yml file from the database. About the DBMS, yes. I've been using symfony with MySQL for years without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `t.typtype` clause doesn't make any sense there.  The query is broken in that regard.  You should report this to the authors.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is published here: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9152