# doctrine:build-schema error

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

When I am trying to run *symfony doctrine:build-schema* command to fetch the schema structure to the yaml file, I got the error:

```
    SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"                                               
  LINE 6: ...                                                  t.typtype ...                                                        
                                                               ^. Failing Query: "SELECT                                            
                                                       ordinal_position as attnum,                                                  
                                                       column_name as field,                                                        
                                                       udt_name as type,                                                            
                                                       data_type as complete_type,                                                  
                                                       t.typtype AS typtype,                                                        
                                                       is_nullable as isnotnull,                                                    
                                                       column_default as default,                                                   
                                                       (                                                                            
                                                         SELECT 't'                                                                 
                                                           FROM pg_index, pg_attribute a, pg_class c, pg_type t                     
                                                           WHERE c.relname = table_name AND a.attname = column_name                 
                                                           AND a.attnum > 0 AND a.attrelid = c.oid AND a.atttypid = t.oid           
                                                           AND c.oid = pg_index.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY (pg_index.indkey)       
                                                           AND pg_index.indisprimary = 't'                                          
                                                           AND format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) NOT LIKE 'information_schema%'  
                                                       ) as pri,                                                                    
                                                       character_maximum_length as length                                           
                                                     FROM information_schema.COLUMNS                                                
                                                     WHERE table_name = 'application'                                               
                                                     ORDER BY ordinal_position"
```

I am in the process of learning symfony/doctrine. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Symfony version 1.4.8

Comment: Ah, right, I have found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478986/symfony-doesnt-like-postgresql-with-doctrinebuild-schema

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to be already addressed on symphony tracker, the patch published on http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9152 resolved the problem.